# ng-repeat and "Controller as"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm stumped by the example in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ao3m49mp/2/). I'm setting a controller on the element that has ng-repeat, so that a new controller instance is created for each item. Since ng-repeat creates a new scope for each item, the controller should take over the newly created scope such that for `ng-repeat="item in items"`, `item` becomes `$scope.item` on the controller. If I use regular controller convention by injecting $scope, this works fine as shown in the example. However, what I *thought* to be the analogous syntax for "Controller as" does not work, e.g. if I define `ng-controller="FirstCtrl as first"`, then for `ng-repeat="item in items"`, `item` is **not** available as `this.item`. Why is this?

Comment: I guess because `$scope != this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said it yourself :

> such that for **`ng-repeat="item in items"`**, **`item`** becomes
>   **`$scope.item`** on the controller.

It becomes available on the `$scope`, not on `this`. And, as pointed out by Yoshi, `$scope` is not the same as `this`. (There's some [good resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers) on that matter on SO)

If you're wondering *"why can I still see the numbers then ?"*, that's because you're accessing `items` from the parent controller.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ng-init to make the scope item available to the controller:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items"
     ng-controller="ItemController as ctrl"
     ng-init="ctrl.init( item )"> 
     ...
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
.controller('ItemController,[
    function(){
        this.init = function(item){
            this.item = item;
        }
    }
])
```

**Updated fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/xvdj07q9/3